# bash script: a more elegant way to retrieve the most current version of go?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, grep, curl

*Caveat*: Both this little bash line and the question here are for learning purposes, as I realize that I could "just open a browser".

Unless I am mistaken, Google does not provide a script-friendly way to download the latest version of golang. Scripts I have seen (such as this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jacoelho/fb989f8c25c3ca7d5db5)) still require you to know and to manually input the go version number.

*My goal* was to see if I could automatically retrieve the latest version without looking it up.

*My solution* does work but I would love to learn a leaner and cleaner way :

```
GOURL=$(curl https://golang.org/dl/ 2>&1 | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2 | awk '/tar.gz/' | awk NR==1)
```

In a nutshell, it gets all links from golang's download page, cleans up the urls to only keep the tar.gz ones, and finally retains the first line of the output which is the exact link I would need. Right now: it would be for [go.1.8.3](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz).

Once again, this is for learning purposes. Thanks for your time.

***EDIT:*** I 'accepted' [GMaster's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368483/197031) as the answer as it improved my solution with no additional tools. I am grateful to other commenters however for helping me discover extra tools. Although I eagerly look forward to any possible additions in the future, I thought it best to close this since my request was amply addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the https://golang.org/dl/ page, you will see the latest versions are in Featured Downloads. Now, assuming Google does not change the html structure of the page, this is a cleaner version

```
GOURL=$(curl -s https://golang.org/dl/ | grep 'download.*downloadBox' | grep -o 'https.*linux.*gz')
```

Comment: If you can use [Pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup): `curl https://golang.org/dl/ -s | pup 'a.downloadBox:parent-of(div:contains("Linux")) attr{href}'` (Or `pup 'a.downloadBox[href*="linux"] attr{href}'`)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had jq installed but this is a step up from that!

Answer (score 2):

Elegance is mostly subjective.  The easy way to keep an eye on Go releases is to set a watch at the [releases](https://github.com/golang/go/releases) page at GitHub, or just add the [relevant feed](https://github.com/golang/go/releases.atom) to your news feeds (assuming you're using RSS feeds, that is).

But if you must have a command that looks more clever than `curl` + `grep`, here's one using [Xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html):

```bash
{ echo -n url=; xidel https://golang.org/dl/ -s -e '//a[./div="Source"]/@href'; } | \
    curl -s -S -O -K -
```

Here `xidel` extracts the relevant URL from the download page using XPath, then `curl` downloads it.  Probably way overkill here, but `xidel` might come in handy for other tasks.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I just downloaded xidel and I look forward to learning to use it. I certainly don't mind overkill when it comes to learning!

Comment: @Farhang The point of using `xidel` (and `pup`, as pointed out in the comment to the other answer) is to parse the structure of the page to locate the relevant URL.  In principle that's safer than `grep` because `grep` could be fooled to match other parts of the page, especially as the page changes over time.  But in this particular case it's a very simple page, `grep` should likely keep working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a Bash script. `xidel` is all you need to parse the golang website.
And no need for `curl` either if you want to download the file.

To extract the url of the latest golang's source:

```bsh
$ xidel -s "https://golang.org/dl" -e '//a[div="Source"]/resolve-uri(@href)'
#or
$ xidel -s "https://golang.org/dl" -e 'resolve-uri(//tr[td="Source"]/td/a/@href[1])'
https://golang.org/dl/go1.16.5.src.tar.gz
```

You could of course download this url with `curl`...

```
$ curl -LO "$(xidel -s "https://golang.org/dl" -e '//a[div="Source"]/resolve-uri(@href)')"
```

...but `xidel` can do that too...

```
$ xidel -s "https://golang.org/dl" -f '//a[div="Source"]/resolve-uri(@href)' --download '.'
```

...which downloads *'go1.16.5.src.tar.gz'* to the current dir.